# How to write chunks with HDF5 in julia when ndims can vary at runtime?

Tags: julia, hdf5

If I had 1000 slices of a 64x64 image, I could write in 64x64x1 chunks like this:

```
using HDF5

filename = "test.h5"
# open file
fmode ="w"
# get a file object
fid = h5open(filename, fmode)
# matrix to write in chunks
B = rand(64,64,1000)
# figure out its dimensions
sizeTuple = size(B)
ndims = length(sizeTuple)
# set up to write in chunks of sizeArray
sizeArray = ones(Int, ndims)
[sizeArray[i] = sizeTuple[i] for i in 1:(ndims-1)] # last value of size  array is :...:,1
# create a dataset models within root
dset = d_create(fid, "models", datatype(Float64), dataspace(size(B)), "chunk", sizeArray)
[dset[:,:,i] = slicedim(B, ndims, i) for i in 1:size(B, ndims)]
close(fid)
```

And this works just fine, but the assignment syntax in dset[:,:,i] is specific to ndims = 3. How can I change that if I had 1000 slices of an arbitrary hyperrectangle specified at runtime? E.g., for B = rand(64,64,3,1000) or rand(64,64,64,3,1000)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the answer from the julia users group on Google after a couple of misfires here. It's delightfully simple:

```
    using HDF5

    filename = "test.h5"
    # open file
    fmode ="w"
    # get a file object
    fid = h5open(filename, fmode)
    # matrix to write in chunks
    B = rand(64,64,1000)
    # figure out its dimensions
    Ndims = ndims(B)
    # set up to write in chunks of sizeArray
    sizeArray = ones(Int, Ndims)
    [sizeArray[i] = size(B, i) for i in 1:(Ndims-1)] # last value of size array is :...:,1
    # create a dataset models within root
    dset = d_create(fid, "models", datatype(Float64), dataspace(size(B)), "chunk", sizeArray)
    # write in slices of (:,:,i) 
    [dset[(fill(:,Ndims-1))...,i] = slicedim(B, Ndims, i) for i in 1:size(B, Ndims)]
    close(fid)
```

The fill and splat ... syntax is very, very useful.